# How to manage long code in a single file aside from code-folding?

Tags: php, c++, ide, folding, code-folding

On the CodeLite website it has the following statement:

> ...over 13 thousand lines!
>   Seeing its individual functions is hard. One solution (yes, there are
>   others) is to fold the code.

What others do they mean when they say "yes there are others"? How else can you visually manage large bodies of code aside from code folding?

(For PHP and C++ in particular)

Comment: Please could you include the languages that you are interested in, because, for example, there are some features for C++ that may not be applicable to other languages.

Comment: @iwbnwif Okay, done. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 tools in CodeLite that are useful to navigate huge source files.

1. Zoom Navigator
2. Outline View

Zoom Navigator should work with any source (or other text) file. What it does is simply to show the source file in a separate window but with a much small font size. You can then scroll through the tiny lines quickly and click on an area of interest to bring that part into the main editor window.

Zoom Navigator is a plugin that come with the default installation, but may need to be enabled from the Plugins menu (Manage Plugins...).

Outline View is a tab in the Workspace view area. For this to work, the file needs to be part of the current Workspace and I think that either CTags or Clang (i.e. code completion) need to be working correctly. Therefore, AFAIK this will only work with C / C++ but it may also work with PHP and other files if there is a suitable parser.

Outline view lists all the classes in a file, and all the function and data members of each class. A slight drawback is that it doesn't sort the lists into alphabetical order, instead they follow the order in the source file.